# Как можно определить и инициализировать массив объектов только одним оператором?

Tags: java, массивы

Такое условие у задачи. Варианты, которые мне известны, не соответствуют данному условию:

1)

```
MyClass[] classes = new MyClass[]{new N1(), new N2() ...};
```

2)

```
A n1 = new A(...);
B n2 = new B(...);
MyClass[] classes = new MyClass[]{n1, n2 ...};
```

3)

```
ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        A n1 = new A(...);
        B n2 = new B(...);
        ....
        Collections.addAll(list, n1, n2 ...); }
```

В примере №1 используются операторы для создания объектов при инициализации массива. в примере №2 объекты инициализируются отдельно, а при инициализации массива мы в его вносим ссылки на эти объекты, что тоже не совсем соответствует условию, аналогично и в примере №3.

Может есть еще варианты, и объявить и инициализировать массив все-таки можно использую только один оператор?  Или я неправильно понимаю это условие задачи. Подскажите пожалуйста!

Вот точный текст условия:

> С помощью одного оператора определить и инициализировать массив из не менее 20 покупок

Comment: а как-то так MyClass[] myClassArray = {new N1(), new N2() ...};

Answer (score 1):

Если конструктор класса не имеет параметров, то можно сделать так:

```
MyClass[] array = IntStream.range(0, 20).boxed()
        .map(i -> new MyClass())
        .toArray(MyClass[]::new);
```

**UPD:** вариант от @Alex Chermenin

```
MyClass[] array = Stream.generate(MyClass::new)
        .limit(20)
        .toArray(MyClass[]::new);
```

Comment: Или так: `MyClass[] array = Stream.generate(MyClass::new).limit(20).toArray(MyClass[]::new);`

Comment: В моем случае конструкторы классов имеют параметры.

Answer (score 1):

еще такой вариант можно:

```
    List<MyClass> objects = Arrays.asList(new N1(), new N2());

    List<MyClass> objects2 = new ArrayList<MyClass>(){
        {
            this.add(new N1());
            this.add(new N2());
        }
    };
```